Xcode 16.2: iPhone SE 18.1 simulator screen is blank "external display"
I run into some Xcode 16.2 novelty I dunno how to work around:
simulator screen is blank. Where's the image? (It's not on the physical iPhone either)
I/O -> External Displays is set to "Disabled"
Sadly s.o. won't allow to attach pictures :-[

I had to launch the app in iOS 18.2 simulator to resuscitate
the 18.1 simulator where the problem was exibiting itself.
